# Maximum cardinality of an orthonormal set

Tags: linear-algebra

We know that in an orthonormal set of vectors each pair of vectors is orthogonal. Geometrically, that means they are perpendicular to each other.

Now if I consider a $2$-dimensional space, then we can't have more than $2$ vectors which are perpendicular to each other, because in $2$ dimensional space we can't have $3$ vectors which are perpendicular to one another.

So my question is:

> Can we have an orthonormal set of more than $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ ?

Comment: Did you understand?

Comment: yes i got it. Thanks....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The reason:

> **Claim:** Orthogonal vectors are linearly independent.

*Proof:* Assume that $v,w\in\mathbb{R}^n\backslash\{0\}$ are orthogonal. That means $\langle v,w\rangle=0$. Now assume that $v$ and $w$ are linearly dependent. Then $v=\lambda w$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\}$. Therefore

$$0=\langle v,w\rangle = \lambda \langle w,w\rangle = \lambda \|w\|^2$$

Dividing by $\|w\|^2$ gives $\lambda=0$. Contradiction. $\square$

There cannot be a linearly independent set with more than $n$ elements in $\mathbb{R}^n$, since the dimension of this vector space is $n$.